# How can I reach object values or functions from my method function?

Tags: javascript

How can I reach values or functions in my object from my methods function?

Example:

```
function Game(playerName) {
  this.player = playerName;
  this.scoreWins = 0;
  this.scoreLoses = 0;

  this.getCheckLetter = function () {
    document.onkeyup = myKeyUpHandler;

  function myKeyUpHandler() {
    firstName = this.player;
    console.log(firstName);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your goal?

Comment: FYI, since `myKeyUpHandler` isn't part of `Game`'s prototype, it won't have access to `this` as an instance of `Game`

Comment: this looks messy..

Comment: I want to figure out how to get players name in my methods function

Answer (score 1):

First is that you should tend to use `[element].addEventListener(...)` instead of `document.on[event name]` as some script could remove your event listener on accident later on.

Next is that when you bind an event listener, the `this` inside the event listener function becomes the element that the event listener is on. In order to avoid this, you must specifically *bind* the function to another object. In thise case, I bind the `this.myKeyUpHandler` to `this`, aka the `Game` object.

The output of you hitting keys on after focusing the document is that you receive some console notifications with the initiated player's name.

```js
function Game(playerName) {
  this.player = playerName;
  this.scoreWins = 0;
  this.scoreLoses = 0;
  
  this.myKeyUpHandler= function() {
    firstName = this.player;
    console.log(firstName);
  }

  document.addEventListener('keyup', this.myKeyUpHandler.bind(this));
  
}

let Paul = new Game("Paul");
```

Comment: [Some more info on function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)